# How to send data from Android/iOS app to a python script running on a raspberry pi using Bluetooth?

Tags: python, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

So me and my friend are working on this project where a raspberry pi with certain sensors collects some data and outputs it.

Now, we want certain parameters to be passed on runtime. So we were thinking of creating a react-native app which could connect with the Pi using Bluetooth. Once connected, it could then send the arguments over Bluetooth.

The python script would then intercept these arguments and then run its program and then send its output back to the app.

While searching for libraries to help me with this, I came across this library: `https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx`

While going through the documentation, I came across `https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/wiki/Characteristic-Writing`, which seems to be the method used for writing some data and sending it.

In Bluetooth terms, what exactly are these services and characteristics and do I have to create my own service and characteristic while working on my project? Or can I write to any existing characteristic so that the python script can read that?

If I have wrongly understood certain concepts, please correct me. Also if there are any better ways to architect this approach please let me know

Comment: I am trying to do something similar for a project. Were you able to make BLE work? If yes, what did you do

Comment: @pesky_programmer That project fell through, so I did not work on it

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no official Expo Bluetooth API. I looked up the same library you are looking at and I find it a little complicated.

I found this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/838697/share-files-between-2-computers-via-bluetooth-from-terminal, where you could open up one terminal and use `Bluetoothctl` to connect to a specific device. Now, open up another terminal and use the `bluetooth-sendto --device= MAC:ADDRESS` (read that link) to send the file from Raspberry Pi to a phone (I tested on Android and it worked).

You could also send data from the phone to Raspberry Pi. Again, check out that link.